# Pandas - Create xlsx from dict & array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose i have the following array:

```
x = [
{
    "id": "1",
    "array": ["2", "3", "4"]
 },
{
    "id": "2",
    "array": ["5"]
 },
{
    "id": "3",
    "array": ["6", "7", "8"]
}
]
```

I am trying to create a spreadsheet using pandas, and i have the challenge to merge the content of an array that lives inside a dict to be part of the columns as well, once that the array got created in a dynamic way.

Current approach:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': []})

for item in x:
    df = df.append(item, ignore_index=True)

df.to_excel('test.xlsx', 's')
```

Current output:

```
    id  array
0   1   ['2', '3', '4']
1   2   ['5']
2   3   ['6', '7', '8']
```

Expected output:

```
    id  array
0   1   2   3   4
1   2   5
2   3   6   7   8
```

Any ideas?

Comment: it is not clear what the expect output is, you want one column named array that has "2 3 4" at index 0?

Comment: Forgot to specify: i want to create each item inside the array as a independent column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `join`

```
df.array=df.array.apply(' '.join)
df
Out[211]: 
  id  array
0  1  2 3 4
1  2      5
2  3  6 7 8
```

Update

```
pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(df.array.tolist())],1)
Out[249]: 
  id      array  0     1     2
0  1  [2, 3, 4]  2     3     4
1  2        [5]  5  None  None
2  3  [6, 7, 8]  6     7     8
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
Just to add up, you can remove the other array with:
    df.drop(['array'], axis=1)

Answer (score 1):

you don't need any loop

just create a df with list of dictionaries

```
 df=pd.DataFrame(x)
 #join the list elements with ' '
 df['array']=df['array'].str.join(' ')
```